# Excluding directory when creating a .tar.gz file

Tags: linux, gzip, tar, compression

I have a `/public_html/` folder, in that folder there's a `/tmp/` folder that has like 70gb of files I don't really need.

Now I am trying to create a `.tar.gz` of `/public_html/` excluding `/tmp/`

This is the command I ran:

```
tar -pczf MyBackup.tar.gz /home/user/public_html/ --exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp/"
```

The tar is still being created, and by doing an `ls -sh` I can see that `MyBackup.tar.gz` already has about 30gb, and I know for sure that `/public_html/` without `/tmp/` doesn't have more than 1GB of files.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell command to tar directory excluding certain files/folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders)

Comment: the `-p` option has no meaning in terms of the create function, right!?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Try removing the last / at the end of the directory path to exclude

```
tar -pczf MyBackup.tar.gz /home/user/public_html/ --exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp"
```

Comment: To exclude whole folder and its content: tar -pczvf MyBackup.tar.gz /home/user/public_html/ --exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp/*"

Comment: I get `tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.` in macos

Comment: Getting an error tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Comment: Does not work, I had to use `--exclude="/home/user/public_html/tmp` instead of `--exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp`

Comment: Indeed, exclude needs to be specified first

Comment: Disregard my previous comment which I cannot longer edit: `exclude` needs to be specified first as https://stackoverflow.com/users/3904223/oussaka notes. At least that's the only thing that worked for me

Comment: this answer is wrong. tar doesn't even have --exclude "" command. it should be
--exclude=PATTERN      exclude files, given as a PATTERN

Comment: --exclude parameters should be placed BEFORE any sources.

Comment: Works perfectly - FreeBSD 13

Answer (score 74):

Try moving the `--exclude` to before the include.

```
tar -pczf MyBackup.tar.gz --exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp/" /home/user/public_html/
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on an old Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box.

Comment: I needed to do this on OS X as well.

Comment: Worked for me after removing trailing slashes:
`tar -pczf MyBackup.tar.gz --exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp" /home/user/public_html`

Answer (score 30):

The correct command for exclude directory from compression is :

```
tar --exclude='./folder' --exclude='./upload/folder2' -zcvf backup.tar.gz backup/
```

Make sure to put **--exclude before the source and destination items**.

and you can check the contents of the tar.gz file without unzipping :

```
tar -tf backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks... This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 22):

Yes, remove the trailing `/` and (at least in ubuntu 11.04) all the paths given must be relative or full path. You can't mix absolute and relative paths in the same command.

```
sudo tar -czvf 2011.10.24.tar.gz ./start-directory --exclude "home/user/start-directory/logs"
```

will not exclude logs directory but

```
sudo tar -czvf 2011.10.24.tar.gz ./start-directory --exclude "./start-directory/logs"
```

will work

Comment: Work for me when i remove absolute path in exclude argument.

Comment: The tip about mixing absolute and relative paths was key for me here

Answer (score 7):

You can also exclude more than one using only one `--exclude`. Like this example:

```
tar -pczf MyBackup.tar.gz --exclude={"/home/user/public_html/tmp","/home/user/public_html/data"} /home/user/public_html/
```

In `--exclude=` you must finish the directory name without `/` and must in between **MyBackup.tar.gz** and **/home/user/public_html/**

The syntax is:

```
tar <OPTIONS> <TARBALL_WILL_CREATE> <ARGS> <PATH_TO_COMPRESS>
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me, running unxutils tar on windows10. Instead, I had to put the files/dirs to archive as the **last** parameter, like this:

```
tar -pczf MyBackup.tar.gz --exclude "/home/user/public_html/tmp/" /home/user/public_html/
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
tar -zcvf target.tar.gz target/ --exclude="target/backups" --exclude="target/cache"
```

Answer (score 4):

`tar -pczf <target_file.tar.gz> --exclude /path/to/exclude --exclude /another/path/to/exclude/* /path/to/include/ /another/path/to/include/*`

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10.

1. The `=` after `exclude` is optional. You can use `=` instead of space after keyword `exclude` if you like.
2. Parameter `exclude` must be placed before the source.
3. The difference between use folder name (like the 1st) or the * (like the 2nd) is: the 2nd one will include an empty folder in package but the 1st will not.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
tar -pczvf advancedarts.tar.gz /home/user/public_html/ --exclude /home/user/public_html/tmp
```

Answer (score -2):

The exclude option needs to include the `=` sign and `"` are not required.

```
--exclude=/home/user/public_html/tmp
```

Comment: " is required if the folder has space in the name