# How to use 'cp' command to exclude a specific directory?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command, cp

I want to copy all files in a directory except some files in a specific sub-directory.
I have noticed that `cp` command didn't have the `--exclude` option.
So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: [rsync?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230342/scp-r-but-leave-out-exclude-a-specified-subdirectory)

Comment: `tar -c | tar -x` ?

Comment: @mvds, agree with you, using tar with '--exclude' is a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy folder recursively, excluding some folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders)

Answer (score 1147, accepted):

`rsync` is fast and easy:

```
rsync -av --progress sourcefolder /destinationfolder --exclude thefoldertoexclude
```

You can use `--exclude` multiples times.

```
rsync -av --progress sourcefolder /destinationfolder --exclude thefoldertoexclude --exclude anotherfoldertoexclude
```

**Note that the dir `thefoldertoexclude` after `--exclude` option is relative to the `sourcefolder`, i.e., `sourcefolder/thefoldertoexclude`.**

Also you can add `-n` for dry run to see what will be copied before performing  real operation, and if everything is ok, remove `-n` from command line.

Comment: Agreed, you can't beat the simplicity and power of `--exclude`

Comment: is the `thefoldertoexclude` relative to the `sourcefolder` or the current working dir? thanks

Comment: It's relative to the source folder. This will exclude the folder source/.git from being copied. rsync -r --exclude '.git' source target

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think it's a good practice to add "switches" before "parameters". Also the man page of rsync reports --exclude usable as with the "=" syntax or without. So to standarize across operating systems, I'd use `rsync -av --progress --exclude="thefoldertoexclude" sourcefolder /destinationfolder` - anyway upvote for the rsync instead of the find, as you can easily use absolute paths for the source while in the find it's trickier as it uses the `{}` in the dst.

Comment: I am sorry but rsync is not installed by default on any system I know of, tar OTOH is.

Comment: Can I use it in case of file transfer across machines (like scp)?

Comment: @XaviMontero definitely not, as you add many of those switches, it will get lost what is the actual folder being copied. imaging having, 5 exclude switches. Some args are good to have them at the end, i think

Comment: I think slash at wrong place,`rsync -av --progress sourcefolder/ destinationfolder --exclude thefoldertoexclude`

Comment: @mamun Of course e.g. from remote server to local machine: 
`$ rsync user@example.com:/var/www/mypage /var/www/mylocalpage/` or from local to remote
`$ rsync /var/www/mylocalpage/ user@example.com:/var/www/mypage`

Comment: Unfortunately I found that `rsync` are ~4x slower then `cp` command :( at least on my VM even when I'm including big `.git` directory in `cp` task and excluding in `rsync`.

Comment: Unfortunately rsync cannot coppy as symlink :(

Comment: This command is purely magic, it doesn't overwrite the unchanged files, it also shows you the time and the transfer speed, also shows you which file where copied only the different ones !!

Comment: how can I exclude multiple folders/files with this? thanks

Comment: @Yugi you can add --exclude multiple times for another folders

Comment: @orkoden Here on Ubuntu exclude works relative to the current working dir (which is really unintuitive)

Comment: @XaviMontero and if you want to exclude multiple folders you can use rsync like this rsync -av --progress --exclude={"thefoldertoexclude","anotherfolder","folder2"} sourcefolder /destinationfolder

Comment: Ahh good to know @HódosGábor. I always gave multiple `--exclude` options by typing them all. Nice compact format!

Comment: @hank what is the use of `-a` in above as per the man page it is for archiving or for appending data onto shorter files?

Comment: `--exclude /node_modules/` will exclude node_modules anywhere in the source tree. So powerful while copying a bunch of JavaScript/Node.js project folders.

Comment: The exclude explanation appears to be incorrect.  According to the man page it will "exclude files matching PATTERN" so that pattern doesn't have to be relative to the source folder, it's simply a pattern

Comment: `-av` means `--archive --verbose`. From rsync manpage on archive option: "This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a notable omission). The only exception to the above equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied."

Answer (score 141):

Well, if exclusion of certain filename patterns had to be performed by every unix-ish file utility (like cp, mv, rm, tar, rsync, scp, ...), an immense duplication of effort would occur. Instead, such things can be done as part of [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globbing), i.e. by your shell.

## bash

[`man 1 bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), <kbd>/</kbd> **extglob**.

Example:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo images/*
images/004.bmp images/033.jpg images/1276338351183.jpg images/2252.png
$ echo images/!(*.jpg)
images/004.bmp images/2252.png
```

So you just put a pattern inside `!()`, and it negates the match. The pattern can be arbitrarily complex, starting from enumeration of individual paths (as Vanwaril shows in another answer): `!(filename1|path2|etc3)`, to regex-like things with stars and character classes. Refer to the manpage for details.

## zsh

[`man 1 zshexpn`](https://www.mankier.com/1/zshexpn), <kbd>/</kbd> **filename generation**.

You can do `setopt KSH_GLOB` and use bash-like patterns. Or,

```
% setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
% echo images/*
images/004.bmp images/033.jpg images/1276338351183.jpg images/2252.png
% echo images/*~*.jpg
images/004.bmp images/2252.png
```

So **`x~y`** matches pattern **`x`**, but excludes pattern **`y`**. Once again, for full details refer to manpage.

---

## fish<sup><sup>new!</sup></sup>

The [fish](https://fishshell.com/) shell has a [much prettier answer](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3681#issuecomment-269324594) to this:

```
 cp (string match -v '*.excluded.names' -- srcdir/*) destdir
```

---

#### Bonus pro-tip

Type `cp *`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> and just see what happens. <sup>it's not harmful <sup>I promise</sup></sup>

Comment: @MikhailGolubtsov perhaps that's because globbing is not recursive and works one level at a time. Edited out.
P.S: it works in `zsh` though.

Comment: Nice pro-tip! This way you can remove single items easily. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, to turn off extended pattern matching features in Bash, run `setopt -u extglob`.

Comment: "... an immense duplication of effort..." shouldn't it be just a one-liner: exclude paths from the list that match a regex? How the file manipulating utilities like `cp` don't support this most simple and straightforward use case out of the box is beyond me. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @ayorgo well yes it "should" — but in C, a oneliner can't do much: multiply some ints and maybe move a pointer, that's it. Even ignoring the source level, regex matching in C involves additional library dependency and additional machine code output — now *multiply* this by the number of commands, and you've got nontrivial (unbounded?..) overhead. At least that's my understanding why it was "refactored" to the shell; I can totally relate to the subpar UI aspect of it, but hopefully you can also see the technical justification now. Best wishes!

Comment: what about POSIX sh?

Comment: @t7e in that case, I'm afraid, you're restricted to `find ... | xargs`.

Answer (score 68):

Why use `rsync` when you can do:

```
find . -type f -not -iname '*/not-from-here/*' -exec cp '{}' '/dest/{}' ';'
```

This assumes the target directory structure being the same as the source's.

Comment: I think you need the `-path` argument to test path hierarchies, not -iname

Comment: And you'll also need a semi-colon at the end: `find . -type f -not -path '*/not-from-here/*' -exec cp '{}' '/dest/{}' \;`

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson Thanks Matthew, go ahead an edit my answer.

Comment: Wow, it won't let me: "Edits must be at least 6 characters" !

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson Meh. Those restrictions will be lifted, as soon as you gain a little more rep. I edited the answer accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: Why, thank you, @Henning for pointing that out. Although this answer is now more than three years old, it never occurred to me that `rsync` might actually be a shorter command. Wait. No. It did. That's why I mentioned it. Now it's up to you to supply that answer right here. Just because mine is the accepted answer doesn't mean yours could outscore it. Go for it.

Comment: @Henning why not `rsync`? Coz it may be not present in the system! while `find`, `cp` is always on their places. Or you from kind of guys, who installed 2gigs of stuff to do simple things?

Comment: What if `/dest/` do not have required directory structure?

Comment: @xuhdev Hence the disclaimer in the answer. It only works when the target directory structure is the same as the source's.

Comment: My fix for that - somewhere below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485164/1707015

Comment: What if I want to exclude folders as well?

Answer (score 47):

```
cp -r `ls -A | grep -v "c"` $HOME/
```

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10 .sh

Comment: Made a shell function which simplifies the usage for custom source path and exclusion of just one file or directory:

`# $1 = source path
# $2 = destination path
# $3 = filter
copy_from_source_to_destination_except_filter() {
 cp -r $(ls -A $1 | grep -v -w $3 | awk -v path=$1 '{printf "%s/%s ", path, $1}') $2
}`

Comment: fails with directories with spaces

Comment: @Sérgio I haven't tested it but `cp -r "$(ls -A | grep -v "c")" $HOME/` should work. The command in the answer fails because there `cp` operates on the output of `ls -A | grep -v "c"`, which is unquoted and therefore breaks on spaces. `"$(…)"` is the same as ``"`…`"`` but easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 42):

The easiest way I found, where you can copy all the files excluding files and folders just by adding their names in the parentheses:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r !(Filename1 | FoldernameX | Filename2) Dest/
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I get `-bash: !: event not found`

Comment: shopt -s extglob (execute this to enable ! in cp, rm and others)

Comment: @geneorama This happens if history substitution is enabled. https://serverfault.com/a/208414/352016

Comment: Nice tip, but it does not work in sh.

Comment: It should be `cp -r !(Filename1|FoldernameX|Filename2) Dest/` without the spaces inside the parantheses.

Answer (score 33):

It's relative to the source directory. 
This will exclude the directory `source/.git` from being copied.

```
rsync -r --exclude '.git' source target
```

Comment: What is the difference/improvement compared to the top answer?

Comment: @reducingactivity less obsolete flags

Comment: I feel like the '-a' in the first answer is better than plain old -r: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-a

Comment: @reducingactivity nothing much but simple to digest as the expression is shorter, just my personal preference

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on [mvds’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4585929#comment5036408_4585929), this works for me

```
cd dotfiles
tar -c --exclude .git --exclude README . | tar -x -C ~/dotfiles2
```

Comment: The nice thing about tar, you can use exclude.tag files to ignore directories  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280610/722796 also https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html

Answer (score 14):

`rsync` is actually quite tricky. have to do multiple tests to make it work.

Let's say you want to copy `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/dev` but need to **exclude** `/var/www/html/site/video/` directory maybe due to its size. The command would be:

`rsync -av --exclude 'sites/video' /var/www/html/ /var/www/dev`

Some *caveat*:

1. The last slash `/` in the source is needed, otherwise it will also copy the source directory rather than its content and becomes `/var/www/dev/html/xxxx`, which maybe is not what you want.
2. The the `--exclude` path is **relative** to the source directly. Even if you put full absolute path, it will not work.
3. `-v` is for verbose, `-a` is for archive mode which means you want *recursion* and want to preserve almost everything.

Comment: a simple solution that take cares of  special characters and white spaces

Comment: Thanks for explaining parameters, unlike the current top answer!

Comment: how about multiple folder to exclude?

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm You probably figured it out by now, but for posterity's sake: you can add multiple `--exclude` flags, like: `--exclude 'foo' --exclude 'bar'`

Answer (score 13):

```
cp -rv `ls -A | grep -vE "dirToExclude|targetDir"` targetDir
```

Edit: forgot to exclude the target path as well (otherwise it would recursively copy).

Comment: watch out for directory entries containing spaces.

Answer (score 10):

rsync

```
rsync -r --verbose --exclude 'exclude_pattern' ./* /to/where/
```

and first try it with -n option to see what is going to be copied

Comment: What is the difference/improvement compared to the top answer?

Answer (score 9):

I assume you're using bash or dash.  Would this work?

```
shopt -s extglob  # sets extended pattern matching options in the bash shell
cp $(ls -laR !(subdir/file1|file2|subdir2/file3)) destination
```

Doing an ls excluding the files you don't want, and using that as the first argument for cp

Comment: You can skip the extra `ls` and simply do `cp !(file1|file1) dest`.

Comment: Do not use -laR. it add string that interfere with cp. 

`cp $(ls folder/!exclude_folder0|exclude_folder1)) dest`

Answer (score 8):

Just move it temporally into a hidden directory (and rename it after, if wanted).

```
mkdir .hiddendir
cp * .hiddendir -R
mv .hiddendir realdirname
```

Comment: Not pretty maybe – but this is the only option I’ve found here which works with `cp` and a standard POSIX shell like `sh`.

Comment: This answer is dramatically underrated. This is the most compatible, easiest to read and easy to understand answer. Kudos, I don't know why I didn't think of it.

Comment: Thanks @RobertTalada, how far will the answer go from now? ‎️‍

Comment: Obvious drawback is that you might be avoiding copying something because it's too big.

Answer (score 6):

Another simpler option is to install and use rsync which has an ``--exclude-dir` option, and can be used for both local and remote files.

Answer (score 5):

This is a modification of Linus Kleen's answer. His answer didn't work for me because there would be a . added in front of the file path which cp doesn't like (the path would look like source/.destination/file).

This command worked for me:

`find . -type f -not -path '*/exlude-path/*' -exec cp --parents '{}' '/destination/' \;`

the --parents command preserves the directory structure.

Answer (score 4):

`rsync` went unavailable for us. Below is an alternative that works.

```
tar -cf - --exclude='./folder' --exclude='./file.tar' ./source_directory | tar -xf - -C ./destination_directory
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
cp -r `ls -A | grep -v "Excluded_File_or_folder"` ../$target_location -v
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -I "filename1" -I "filename2" | xargs cp -rf -t destdir
```

The first part `ls` all the files but hidden specific files with flag `-I`. The output of `ls` is used as standard input for the second part. `xargs` build and execute command `cp -rf -t destdir` from standard input. the flag `-r` means copy directories recursively, `-f` means copy files forcibly which will overwrite the files in the `destdir`, `-t` specify the destination directory copy to.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv tobecopied/tobeexcluded .
cp -r tobecopied dest/
mv tobeexcluded tobecopied/
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a "do while" loop to read the output of the find command.  In this example, I am matching (rather than excluding) certain patterns since there are a more limited number of pattern matches that I want than that I don't want.  You could reverse the logic with a `-not` in front of the `-iname` flags:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.flac" -o -print0 -iname "*.mp3" -print0 -o -iname "*.wav" -print0 -o -iname "*.aac" -print0 -o -iname "*.wma" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do cp -ruv "$file" "/media/wd/network_sync/music/$file"; done
```

I use the above to copy all music type files that are newer on my server than the files on a Western Digital TV Live Hub that I have mounted at `/media/wd`. I use the above because I have a lot of DVD files, mpegs, etc. that I want to exclude AND because for some reason rsync looks like it is copying, but after I look at the wd device, the files are not there despite no errors during the rsync with this command:

```
rsync -av --progress --exclude=*.VOB --exclude=*.avi --exclude=*.mkv --exclude=*.ts --exclude=*.mpg --exclude=*.iso --exclude=*ar --exclude=*.vob --exclude=*.BUP --exclude=*.cdi --exclude=*.ISO --exclude=*.shn --exclude=*.MPG --exclude=*.AVI --exclude=*.DAT --exclude=*.img --exclude=*.nrg --exclude=*.cdr --exclude=*.bin --exclude=*.MOV --exclude=*.goutputs* --exclude=*.flv --exclude=*.mov --exclude=*.m2ts --exclude=*.cdg --exclude=*.IFO --exclude=*.asf --exclude=*.ite /media/2TB\ Data/data/music/* /media/wd/network_sync/music/
```

Answer (score 1):

10 years late. Credits to Linus Kleen.

I hate `rsync`! ;) So why not use `find` and `cp`? And with this answer also `mkdir` to create a non-existent folder structure.

`cd /source_folder/ && find . -type d -not -path '*/not-from-here/*' -print -exec mkdir -p '/destination_folder/{}' \;`

`cd /source_folder/ && find . -type f -not -path '*/not-from-here/*' -print -exec cp -au '{}' '/destination_folder/{}' \;`

It looks like `cd` ìs necessary to concat relative paths with `find`.

`mkdir -p` will create all subfolders and will not complain when a folder already exists.

---

Housten we have the next problem. What happens when someone creates a new folder with a new file in the middle of it? Exactly: it will fail for these new files. (Solution: just run it again! :)) The solution to put everything into one `find` command seems difficult.

---

For clean-up: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627218/239596

Comment: Gave it a try. Current version of your answer creates in the first step directories. Because this step currently contains `-not -path '*/not-from-here/*'`, it will create directory `./not-from-here`. Probably, this is not intended. Therefore, for the first step (directory creation), you probably want `-not -path '*/log'` instead.