# shell command to copy all files except a few files

Tags: bash

I want to copy all files to a directory except a few files. Is there any way to specify that information in the cp command?

Directory structure -

```
Dir
     Dir 1
     Dir 2 -> Dir 2.1 -> file
```

I want to copy the entire dir directory except file.

Comment: [How to use 'cp' command to exclude a specific directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4585929/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `rsync`

```
rsync -av --exclude='path1/to/exclude' --exclude='path2/to/exclude' source destination
```