# Bash: copy entire folder structure excluding certain files

Tags: linux, bash, glob, cp, subdirectory

In Bash, how can I use `cp` to copy a directory structure except those files that match one of a number of patterns, e.g. `*.txt` and `*~`?

I am happy to use

`shopt -s extglob`

if required, and have tried things like

`cp -rp !(*.txt,*~) destination_folder/`

but without success. In the example above, the pattern is not matched in subdirectories, and using `**/!(*.txt,*~)` flattens the directory structure despite the -p option.

Ideally, subdirectories of the source folder should be created in the destination folder tree even if they are/end up empty.

If there is no way of achieving this with `cp`, please suggest an alternative bash command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585929/how-to-use-cp-command-to-exclude-a-specific-directory#14789400

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @triplee: it is not a duplicate of the existing question. The problem is with why the `extglob` done fails for that? The duplicated question just provides alternate ways to do that and not answering the question. Posted to reopen

Comment: @Inian: There is no error, I simply haven't found a solution that does what I want.

Comment: @JohnS.: Can you try `cp -rp -- !(*.txt,*~) destination_folder/`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, tripleee: My question is not a duplicate. Please unmark.

Comment: @Inian: Your suggestion with -- didn't work, I'm afraid. In fact, everything got copied, even a *.txt file the top-level folder.

Comment: @JohnS.: did you enable `shopt -s extglob` before running it. I thought you already did that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138749/discussion-between-john-s-and-inian).