# Exclude directory while copy directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cp

I want to exclude two directories while copying.

**Example:**

```
$ ls /root/tmp
a b c d e f
```

I want to exclude directories `a` and `b`:

```
$ cp -rp /root/tmp/ /root/tmp1/
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585929/how-to-use-cp-command-to-exclude-a-specific-directory) already has an answer

Comment: In this commad only one folder has excluded. I want to exclude two directory's in one command

Comment: try: `ls | grep -Pv '^(a|b)$' | xargs -I xxx echo xxx` in place of `echo` use your `cp` command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 'cp' command to exclude a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585929/how-to-use-cp-command-to-exclude-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 6):

`rsync` can be used to exclude multiple directories like this:

```
rsync -av --exclude=/root/tmp/a --exclude=/root/tmp/b /root/tmp/ /root/tmp1/
```

with `cp` command

```
cp -r /root/tmp/!(a | b) /root/tmp1/
```

Execute  `shopt -s extglob`  before `cp` command to enable `!` in `cp`

Answer (score 2):

Try the below `rsync` it works for me on `ubuntu 14.04`

```
rsync -av --exclude='/root/tmp/a' --exclude='/root/tmp/b' 
/path/to/include /path/to/include /path/to/destination
```

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude the directories as part of find results before the copy, but using `rsync` or `cp` with the `'!'` support enabled as suggested by Sathiya is a much simpler solution.

See `find` example below:

```
find /root/tmp/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -regex '\(.*a\|.*b\)' -exec cp -r {} /root/tmp1/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in bash (does not work in sh):

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r !(somefile|somefile2|somefolder) destfolder/
```