# Copying folders but not tar files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, copy

I have a folder, which consists of many folders and many tar files. (this many is around 1000)

I want to write a script to copy all folders with their contents to another directory, but I do not want to copy tar files.

I already know by writing

> cp -a /source/ /path/

I can copy a directory with its contents to another, but for this case, I do not know how to do it.

As the number of directories are alot, I am not able to each time copy one directory.

I appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789400/6369752) might be what you're looking for.

You want to use the `rsync` command and in the `--exclude` flag you want to put `*.tar`

So your answer will look something like this:
`rsync -r --exclude='*.tar' [source] [destination]`

[This](https://www.lifewire.com/copying-directories-with-rsync-3971105) is also a helpful little tutorial on how to use `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `cp` in `find` to exclude `*.tar` files:

```
dest='/path/'
mkdir "$dest" &&
find /source -mindepth 1 -not -name '*.tar' -exec cp -a {} "$dest" \;
```