# tar exclude single files/directories, not patterns

Tags: tar

I'm using `tar` to make daily backups of a server and want to avoid backup of /proc and /sys system directories, but without excluding any directories named "proc" or "sys" somewhere else in the file tree.

For, example having the following directory tree ("*bla*" being normal files):

```
# find
.
./sys
./sys/bla
./foo
./foo/sys
./foo/sys/bla
```

I would like to exclude `./sys` but **not** `./foo/sys`.

I can't seem to find an `--exclude` pattern that does that...

```
# tar cvf /dev/null * --exclude=sys
foo/
```

or...

```
# tar cvf /dev/null * --exclude=/sys
foo/
foo/sys/
foo/sys/bla
sys/
sys/bla
```

Any ideas?
(Linux Debian 6)

Comment: Are you sure there is no exclude? If you are using MAC OS it is a different story! Look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html#SEC108)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. There is a `--exclude` option, but I don't know how to match it for single, absolute file names (not any file by that name) - see my examples above.

Comment: Look here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify absolute paths to the exclude pattern, this way other `sys` or `proc` directories will be archived:

```
tar --exclude=/sys --exclude=/proc /
```

Comment: True, but the important detail about this is that the excluded file name must match exactly the notation reported by the `tar` listing. For my example that would be `./sys` - as I just found out now.

Answer (score 7):

Using tar you can exclude directories by placing a tag file in any directory that should be skipped.

Create tag files,

```
touch /sys/.exclude_from_backup
touch /proc/.exclude_from_backup
```

Then,

```
tar -czf backup.tar.gz --exclude-tag-all=.exclude_from_backup *
```

Comment: Good idea in theory but often /sys and /proc cannot be written to.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you might want to use:

```
--anchored --exclude=sys/\*
```

because in case your tar does not show the leading "/" you have a problem with the filter.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you! I wanted to exclude a specific directory, not all directories/subdirectories matching the pattern. bsdtar does not have "--anchored" option though, and with bsdtar we can use full paths to exclude specific folders.

Comment: ah found it! in bsdtar the anchor is "^": `bsdtar cvjf test.tar.bz2 --exclude myfile.avi --exclude "^myexcludedfolder" *`