# Bash script - "tar czf ..." command ignore parameters

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a simple bash script called `script.sh`

```
!#/bin/bash
tar czf /var/log/apache2/Backup_$(date "+%d-%m-%Y").tar.gz /var/log/apache2/ --exclude='backup*' --exclude='Backup*'
```

When I rund this line in SSH-Console, all works fine but when I run the .sh-script at linux console with `bash ./script.sh`

then the `tar czf ...` command works but ignore the --exclude parameters

Whats wrong? I don't know... :/

Comment: How do you know it ignores the exclude parameter?

Comment: what ignores the exclude parameter? the "bash script" or "tar".

Comment: You have a typo in your shebang, it should read `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!#/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

**UPDATE**

```
#!/bin/bash
tar  -cZf /var/log/apache2/Backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz.gz /var/log/apache2/ --exclude='backup*' --exclude='Backup*'
```

exclude is a pattern...
see these helps: [help1](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/exclude.html)    [help2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/tar-exclude-doesnt-exclude-why) [help3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511406/tar-exclude-single-files-directories-not-patterns)

Comment: No, that does not change anything, only the Filename but the parameter "exclude=" will be ignored, too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use :

```
!#/bin/bash
tar -czf /var/log/apache2/Backup_`date "+%d-%m-%Y"`.tar.gz /var/log/apache2/ --exclude='backup*' --exclude='Backup*'
```