# Exclude directory while using tar

Tags: unix, tar

I use the following command to create a tar.gz

```
tar -pczf domain.com.tar.gz  /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www/
```

The tar.gz file contain the following folders

```
var-->www-->domain.com-->public_html-->www-->then the content of www
```

I want the tar.gz file to contain only the content of `www` without any folder.I tried to use `-C` but i get

> Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive error

```
tar -pczf domain.com.tar.gz -C  /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www/
```

**Edit 1**
I added the `.` but then the `exclude` no longer work and all files have a ./ in their filename

Filename become like .\file.txt in archive

```
tar -pczf domain.com.tar.gz -C  /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www/ . --exclude='/var/www/domain.com/public_html/www/tmp/*'
```

**Real example**

```
tar --exclude='tmp/cookies/*' --exclude='tmp/logs/*' -pczf filterbypass.me.tar.gz -C /var/www/filterbypass.me/public_html/www .
```

I want tar,gz to contain only my files in www , not folders + not ./ in filename

Comment: How did you use `-C`? `tar -C /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www -pczf domain.com.tar.gz  .`?

Comment: check edit ...also there are --exclude in actual command

Comment: Did you add a `.` at the end of your command, otherwise you have nothing to add to the archive...? -C changes the directory, and `.` is the current directory you just changed to that you want added.

Comment: Thanks....but its still not working , check my edit

Comment: See my edited Answer to get what you want ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put the complete path into -C, if you want to tar the content of `www`. Do this instead:

`tar -pczf domain.com.tar.gz -C /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www .`

That way 'www' is the directory to be tarred but omited itself by including it into the -C path. You would than later extract all files of the 'www' directory.

In addtion to your edit (exclude) it must look like this:

`tar --exclude=tmp -pczf domain.com.tar.gz -C /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www .`

**EDIT**

According to your wishes, I found a funny but working solution. You exclude the dirs you want with exclude (see the man page of your tar, there are some with `--no-recurse` option, too) and you will have no `./` syntax at all:

`ls /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www | xargs tar --exclude=tmp -C /var/www/domain.com/public_html/www -pczf domain.com.tar.gz`

The way you give the filenames to the input, is the way tar is storing it. So it is even possible with `-C` to store the files without `./` but you need to pipe the list of `ls` with `| xargs` to tar.....

Comment: Two important points about `tar` and `--exclude`: Don't use *trailing slashes* in your paths and any `--exclude` needs to be the first options in the `tar` command.

Comment: Its nearly there dude.....now i have `www` folder-->file contents.I don't want the file content to be in any folder.Just correct it so that the content are not inside the `www`.

Comment: ok, than extend the -C with www and put a . at the end. I will edit my Answer in a second.

Comment: I use it but now my file contain `./` in filename + i got a file with no name and just a .Check my real example edit

Answer (score 3):

After reading all this good answers for different versions and having solved the problem for myself, I think **there are very small details that are very important, and rare to GNU/Linux general use**, that aren't stressed enough and deserves more than comments.

So I'm not going to try to answer the question for every case, but instead, try to register **where to look** when things doesn't work.

**IT IS VERY IMPORTANT TO NOTICE:**

1. **THE ORDER OF THE OPTIONS MATTER:** it is not the same put the --exclude before than after the file option and directories to backup. This is unexpected at least to me, because in my experience, in GNU/Linux commands, usually the order of the options doesn't matter.
2. **Different tar versions expects this options in different order:** for instance, [@Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders/23065162#23065162) indicates that in GNU tar v 1.26 and 1.28 the excludes comes last, whereas in my case, with GNU tar 1.29, it's the other way.
3. **THE TRAILING SLASHES MATTER**: at least in GNU tar 1.29, **it shouldn't be any**.

In my case, for GNU tar 1.29 on Debian stretch, the command that worked was

```
tar --exclude="/home/user/.config/chromium" --exclude="/home/user/.cache" -cf file.tar  /dir1/ /home/ /dir3/
```

The quotes didn't matter, it worked with or without them.

I hope this will be useful to someone.