# Bash Script to backup my "home" folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How can I skip backing up my "Downloads" folder?

here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Daily backup script

# Create some needed variable
day=$(date +%F)
Folder="/home/ME/"

File="/media/MediaTwo/Copy/UbuntuBackup/$day.tar.gz"

# Backup Server Configuration
tar cpzf $File $Folder

# Remove backup files older than 90 days
find $File* -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: check it here, it may duplicate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tar cpzf $File --exclude=Downloads $Folder
```

Comment: is single quotation needed here?

Comment: @haifzhan I don't understand your question. Where do you think the single quotation will be useful/necessary?

Comment: You can repeat the `--exclude` option to exclude another directory.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to exclude your Downloads folder is to add an option (i.e. `--exclude`) to the `tar` command.

I would suggest modifying line 12 of your code to read:

`tar cpzf $File --exclude "${Folder}Downloads" $Folder`

I think this should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use extended pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob; shopt -s dotglob
tar cpzf "$File" "$Folder"/!(Downloads)
```

Answer (score 1):

I sugest this one for maximum speed on multi core machines :

```
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f $File --exclude=Downloads $Folder
```