# Exclude selected sub-directories while compressing

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, compression, tar

Use this command to exclude sub-directories while compressing but it didn't work:

```
    tar -zcvf slice.tar.gz --exclude=slice/media* --exclude slice/images/doc/* slice
```

It still compresses all the sub-directors inside media and doc. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders

Comment: Also it is better to delete not related tags from the question and add information about version of your `tar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option '--exclude' must be at the beginning of the tar command. And do not forget quotation marks.

Try this: `tar --exclude='slice/media*' --exclude='slice/images/doc/*' -zcvf slice.tar.gz slice`