# File or directory doesn't exists on exclude option using tar

Tags: linux, tar

I can't create a tar file  this way

```
 tar -cvf --exclude='./web/uploads' backup.tar .
```

but `./web/uploads` exists,without the exlude option it works.

Comment: which command works? what is your intention? what is the error message/outcome with the non-working command?

Comment: the message it's on title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you specified `-f` which must precede the tarfile name. So you could also try

`tar -cv --exclude='./web/uploads' -f backup.tar .`

as long as the exclude option precedes source and destination. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/984204/7926064) for more options like

`tar --exclude='./web/uploads' -cvf backup.tar .`